# Docker engine fillingup storage

Tags: docker

I am running docker container on my remote machine. Quiet often, the remote machine runs out of disk space. I usually remove the docker directory in my remote machine and download the image again. Is there a better way?

Comment: Find out what is filling up the disk: volumes, images, containers, ... A handy command to clean up is `docker system prune`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have *dangling volumes*, it may fill up your disk space.

List all dangling volumes

`docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true`

Remove all dangling volumes

`` docker volume rm `docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true` ``